# Formatting multiple choice questions

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I format multiple choice questions so option A from the second question will be under option A from the first question (B, C, D etc. as well)?

**Update:** I just use MS Word in order to write multiple choice questions for exams my students take.

Comment: You gave no context. Are you programming in Javascript? Are you making a test for 4th graders? Is this just a logic question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when you type a) or i) or i. or 1) or similar at the beginning of the line, Word will recognise it and start a bullet list automatically. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the line and Word will auto-insert the next list element. That will take care of the indenting for you:

[image: 1]

The red box in the image above highlights the unordered list, ordered/numbered list, multi-level list, decrease indent and increase indent buttons. Use those while creating your MCQ form.

---

If you want to align in a columnar fashion, either use tables (you can make the borders invisible if you like), or insert **Left Tabs** to align the options (click the Ruler once to insert a Left Tab, then while typing text press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump to the next Left Tab position):

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks but I mean when the choices are in one line and the other choices are beneath them. How can A be exactly under A, and B exactly under B, and C, etc.

Comment: If you use the un/ordered list styles, as highlighted by Karan, Word will do the formatting for you so that the same number of tabs are used for each style

Comment: @Tabor: Checked the edit above - do you mean something like that?

Comment: Yes Karan that's it, I tried the tables as well but the problems with table is that when you write inside the cell it expands as you writing, it is not fixed.

Comment: @Tabor: Yeah, normally text in a table cell wraps automatically, but in case of long unbroken text it will expand the cell (although it might well be possible to fix the cell's width).